# How to use IFS with upstart script?

Tags: newline, upstart, ifs

I want to set IFS variable in upstart pre-start script to new line charakter, but
IFS=$'\12'
doesn't work. How do I have to set IFS variable here - I use before in this script
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"

I tested it when using normal bash script and setting IFS like mentioned before works, but not working when using upstart.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Bash syntax in Upstart scripts. Fortunately, it's easy to simply put a newline between a pair of quotes:

```
IFS='
'
```